# Looking for a specific horror/science fiction children's anthology from the 90s/early 2000s

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens, artificial-intelligence

I'm looking for a specific short story anthology, I'm pretty sure it was a children's book. Among the stories in it were:

1) a story where a girl was investigating her friend's death in a car crash, only to find out a chemical that causes mental retardation was involved, is infected with this chemical and walks into the road where she sees headlights;

2) a story about a girl who discovers her desktop computer is sapient after the employees of a tech shop did some experiments and made a group of computers intelligent, and these computers proceeded to set their owners houses on fire after they were found out, at the end it starts an electrical fire and shows the word "delete" on its screen;

3) a story about a girl named "Lizzie Lizard" who discovers that she is a children's cartoon character (an anthropomorphic lizard), and when she notices the television screen that stretches across the horizon, she frantically cries to the viewer not to turn her off;

4) a story where a boy hears about a government facility accident that occurred near his home, and at the end a four-eyed alien is mind-controlling/threatening his parents and telling him not to alert the government agents to its escape.

I can't remember anything else, but those are the gist of the stories I could remember.

Comment: Sounds like Goosebumps style stories perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Scary Mysteries for Sleep-overs*, Allen B. Ury

> Stories include: Doppelganger, Deadman's Curve, Public Enemy, Suspended Animation, Foxboro Ghost, Hackers, Nothing to be Afraid of, Scenic Route, Into Thin Air, Joy Ride Revisited

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scary_Stories_for_Sleep-overs

[image: cover]

> A new series of whodunits written in the same popular format as Scary Stories for Sleepovers. An evil twin plots to kill and replace his kind brother. A girl is locked in an animated world where nothing is real. These are just some of the hair-raising tales that kids will scream over in the first book of this mysteriously scary new collection. Line illustrations.

[https://www.amazon.com/Scary-Mysteries-Sleepovers-Allen-Ury/dp/0843182202](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0843182202)